# Invalid package file after the update of Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

In our app we use successfully the Google Drive API:

```
/libs/google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/libs/google-http-client-gson-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/google-api-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/google-oauth-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/google-http-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
/libs/google-api-client-android-1.12.0-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev61-1.12.0-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/libs/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.12.0-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/libs/jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r61lv1.12.0-beta/drive/libs/gson-2.1.jar
```

**Four days ago I found the Google API with UPDATE AVAILABLE text then I updated**

[image: Update]

**After the update we have now the following libs:**

```
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-android-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-oauth-client-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-gson-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev69-1.13.2-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-protobuf-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/guava-jdk5-13.0.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/jackson-core-2.0.5.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-http-client-1.13.1-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-api-client-1.13.2-beta.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/gson-2.1.jar
/.google_apis/drive-v2r69lv1.13.2-beta/drive/libs/google-api-client-android-1.13.2-beta.jar
```

After the update we just proceeded with the apk publishing.

About the 2% of our users are reporting **INVALID PACKAGE ERROR** during the installation.

We tried to send the apk with old Google Drive API to this users and it installed fine.

Any suggestion how to understand if the problem is related our app apk or to Google Drive API ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have conflicting libraries. I have to do a similar implementation on the .NET side and I had to download the Google source projects and recompile them instead of using binaries.

I have an example here

http://www.alexroque.com/?p=307

although this is an example of integration with Google drive API.